# Pagination on gridview after clicking link button

Tags: c#, asp.net, pagination

I have a grid view which gets generated on click of a link button. I am not able to persist pagination on the gridview. By the way the grid view which gets generated is a nested grid view.. Here are some code samples..

Link button click event:

```
 protected void lbtnBOLNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
    string yourValue = btn.CommandArgument;
Session["globalselected"] = yourValue;
    populategridview1(ddl_market.SelectedItem.Text, dt_to_integer(Picker1.CalendarDateString), dt_to_integer(Picker2.CalendarDateString), ddl_metric.SelectedItem.Text, yourValue, cond1.SelectedValue, cond2.SelectedValue, cond3.SelectedValue);
}
```

Page Load

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        lbl_status.Text = "";

        populategridview3(ddl_days.SelectedItem.Text, ddl_days1.Text);

            populategridview1(ddl_market.SelectedItem.Text, dt_to_integer(Picker1.CalendarDateString), dt_to_integer(Picker2.CalendarDateString), ddl_metric.SelectedItem.Text, Session["globalselected"].ToString(), cond1.SelectedValue, cond2.SelectedValue, cond3.SelectedValue);

    }
}
```

Gridview pagination

```
protected void GridView3_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gvTemp = (GridView)sender;
    GridView3.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    populategridview3(ddl_days.SelectedItem.Text, ddl_days1.Text);
}
```

My issue is on click of the link button my grid view throws error since Session["globalselected"] is null in page load, it gets initialized later. However, i need to call this method populategridview1 in page load to ensure pagination works for the gridview. How do I enable pagination for the child grid in a situation like this?

Comment: Why do you populate the GridViews from page_load even `if (IsPostBack)`? Only use the appropriate events on postback to reload controls.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: If I remove populate from page load if(isPostBack) i do not even get the grid populated.. only when i do an explicit call to rebind within post back I am able to retain the data for the gridview...

Comment: Cant believe my stupidity.. I had enableviewstate as false in my master page which made me lose all my controls on post back :(